# Hwo to override a generic setting in Bulma

Tags: css, sass, bulma

In an app that uses Bulma, there is a requirement to display URLs with an underline.  However, Bulma's `generic.scss` file specifies that anchor tags have no text decoration (see [here](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/blob/1083f017a06b44d6f1e315de2b384798e69aeb35/sass/base/generic.sass#L65)).  I looked through the [Bulma customization docs](https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/concepts/) for a way to override this setting but do not see any variables to do that.  The current work around is to put `class="is-underlined"` in all the anchor tags in the app...less than ideal.  Is there a way to override this in Bulma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your project you could always update/change the styles, either by

- adding some SCSS file before or after the `bulma.scss`
- adding an additional CSS file in your `index.html`

Using either approach, you can override just about anything. Here's how I do it for additional print styles on link URLs: https://github.com/suterma/bulma-print/blob/main/sass/helpers.scss

You could do for example:

```
/* underline link URLs */
a[href] {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

And add this AFTER your inclusion of bulma.